# Live camera filter

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I need to apply filters directly to the mobile device camera, but currently it is giving me a blank screen, i have tried several methods but none seems to work.

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { Surface, } from 'gl-react-expo';
import ImageFilters from 'react-native-gl-image-filters';

   <Surface style={{
              flex:1
            }}>

                <ImageFilters
                    width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
                    height={Dimensions.get('window').height}
                    temperature={10000}
                    sharpen={1}
                    hue={0.5}
                    blur={0.5}
                >
                    <Node blendFunc={{ src: "one", dst: "one minus src alpha" }}
                        shader={shaders.YFlip}
                        uniforms={camera && {
                            t: () => camera
                        }}
                    >
                        <Camera ref={(c) => camera = c}
                            style={{ flex: 1 }}

                        />
                    </Node>
                </ImageFilters>

            </Surface>
```

Comment: Have you given the browser permission to access the camera?

Comment: yes.   useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
            setHasPermission(status === 'granted');

        })();
        return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }, []);